# What is the function of this choke-like transformer on the PCB side of this RJ45 jack+magnetics connector?

Tags: transformer, ethernet

I came across [this ethernet jack+magnetics connector](http://belfuse.com/pdfs/0826-1X1T-32-F.pdf) the other day and was wondering what the transformer on the PCB side was for. I thought it looked like a choke, but there is a centre tap running through the middle and the choke is usually on the network side. Can anyone explain what it is?

[image]

Comment: It's a Common Mode Choke, isn't it?

Comment: If there is a voltage spike on an incoming line the common-mode choke will prevent it damaging the silicon by transferring the energy of the spike so that it appears on 10, 11 and 12 together i.e. there isn't a differential spike

Comment: @JesúsCastañé Correct, it is indeed a CM choke.

Comment: I create a answer with these comments. Is this ok?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a Common Mode Choke integrated in the RJ45 connector.

If there is a voltage spike on an incoming line the common-mode choke will prevent it damaging the silicon by transferring the energy of the spike so that it appears on 10, 11 and 12 together i.e. there isn't a differential spike.